# How to measure how long does a vaccine last?

Tags: covid-19, immune-system, vaccination

Recently I read someone arguing against pharmaceuticals saying COVID 19 vaccine immunity would last around a year. His argument was that how do they know that it's good for a year if a year has not passed yet.

I answered that maybe it had to do with the fact that diseases mutate and they just measure the rate of mutation of the disease to be able to predict the lasting effect of the vaccine, but I'm not really sure about that, I'm not a medic.

How does it work? and is there a formula for this? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to MedicalSciences.SE! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. As pointed out in your other question here, for [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require prior research information when asking questions. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. This helps to provide an answer which will be more helpful. If you found nothing, what did you Google?

Comment: How can we respond to someone who said something? Who is someone? Link us to the source.